# Find and replace regular expression

Tags: regex

How to find and replace the following with Regex?

I want to change \cite{Davis:Cell:1987} in {Davis:1987}

And \cite{Gehring:GenesCells:1996} into {Gehring:1996}

Many thanks.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Many thanks for all your help. Sorry for my ignorance. I am doing a manual find and replace for a text file containing \cite{Gehring:GenesCells:1996} in scrivener. There is a replacements pattern where I can enter a "Replace" value and a "With" value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice of regex can make the answer slightly different.  With POSIX

```
s/\\cite\{\([^:]*\):[^:]*:\([^}]*\)\}/\\cite{\1:\2}/
```

With PCRE:

```
s/\\cite\{([^:]*):[^:]*:([^}]*)}/\\cite{\1:\2}/
```

Note that in POSIX, the parentheses need to be escaped.

Comment: This one worked for me perfectly and in scrivener I have to use %1 %2 to retrieve the results I want. <br/> [Demo!](http://regex101.com/r/xV0nP6#pcre)

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the elements before the first and after the last colon and use a simple regex replace:

```
s/\\cite\{(.*?):[^}]+:(.*?)\}/{\1:\2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace matches of following regex with empty string:

```
\\cite|:.*(?=:)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gO1tB3)

Comment: Edit: I didn't realise it, but this solution was problematic as it recognise other : : syntax which doesn't necessarily start with \cite